# ¿Cómo puedo ajustar el tamaño de una frase en FPDF?

Tags: php, fpdf

Estoy generando un PDF con datos obtenidos de una Base de Datos, sin embargo, hay un dato que cuando es muy largo se sobrescribe en la misma línea, quisiera saber si se puede hacer un salto de línea al renglón o que se puede hacer, tampoco quisiera disminuir el tamaño de la letra para que se vea bien, ya que dependiendo del dato seleccionado puede ocupar menos espacio.

Adjunto mi código FPDF:

```
$pdf = new FPDF('P', 'mm', 'A4');
    $pdf->SetTextColor(0, 0, 0);

    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->Image('vista/img/constancia.png', 0, 0, 210, 310, 'PNG');

    $pdf->SetFont('times', '', 50);
    $pdf->SetTextColor(0,0,0);
    $pdf->Cell(120, 14, '', 0, 1, 'C');
    $pdf->Cell(120, 12, '', 0, 1, 'C');
    
    $pdf->MultiCell(0, 0, utf8_decode('CERTIFICADO'), 0, 'C');

    //CURSO: Esta parte es la que se sobre escribe 
    $pdf->SetFont('times', 'B', 17);
    $pdf->SetTextColor(0,0,0);
    $pdf->Cell(120, 12, '', 0, 1, 'C');
    $pdf->MultiCell(0, 0, utf8_decode($curso), 0, 'C');

    $pdf->Output();
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te falta añadirle el alto de la línea, es el segundo parámetro:

```
$pdf->MultiCell(0, 10, utf8_decode($curso), 0, 'C');
```

Te envío enlace al manual:

http://www.fpdf.org/es/doc/multicell.htm

Comment: Muchas gracias =) me ayudo perfectamente.